# What is the difference between REST API and REST Service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I m very beginner to APIs. I'm trying to create Rest API using spring boot and java. Then I found these 2 words, REST API and REST Service.(https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/). So my question is What is REST API and what is REST service, or are they similar words to each of them ?

Comment: there are no differences between REST and RESTful as far as APIs are concerned. REST is the set of constraints. RESTful refers to an API adhering to those constraints. It can be used in web services, applications, and software.